# Multiple 'default from' email addresses in Devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to override the Devise mailer to use different default from email addresses for different functions. As I understand it, you can only set this once per mailer.

My code is as follows:

```
if defined?(ActionMailer)
  class Devise::Mailer < Devise.parent_mailer.constantize
    include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

    default from: "Example <email-1@domain.com>"

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
    end

    def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
    end

    def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
    end
  end
end
```

For example, I'd like to default from `email-1@domain.com` for the confirmation instructions and `email-2@domain.com` for the other two. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but this should work

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  opts.merge!(from: "Example <email-1@domain.com>")
  devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
end
```